# What is this "Tx" button on this textbox?

Tags: html, web, internet-explorer-11, forms

I am trying to document an internal web application, and at the top of the edit box, one last button makes no sense to me. (It's hard to search on, because "TX" = Texas)

[image: Screenshot showing the edit buttons on top of the box, including the mysterious "Tx"]

The **T** appears in italics and underlined, the **X** is potentially in subscript.  I've played around with trying to select text and then press the button: no results.

For the B, I, U, the expected bolding, italicizing, and underlining occur.  I've also tested the other icons up there and they behaved in an expected manner.

The **Tx** has a color-change when hovered over (as the other buttons do), and it has the appearance of being pressed in when clicked.  These indicate to me that this **Tx** is meant to be functional, not just a signature saying that this is a Tx-brand TextBox.

So what is **Tx** , and what amazing texty functionality have I been missing out on?

*subquestion - can whatever-the-function-is be replicated with a keyboard shortcut?*

---

Using I.E. 11 because it's required for work. Is this something that prefers other browsers?

UPDATE: I tested it with JAWS's "list form fields" command, but alas, it's yet another "unlabeled button."  Our developers aren't the most 508-compliant ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin is called TinyMCE.  Its official website can be found at https://www.tiny.cloud

The button you are looking at is the "Clear Formatting" button.

In the below link (working example of TinyMCE) - highlight come text and select the format menu - you will see the button complete with its description here:
[image]

Its worth pointing out that this plugin (commonly used on sites powered by WordPress, Joomla and other content managers) can be configured by the developer implementing it and both menus and buttons can be turned on or off, so the example will not look absolutely identical to your example (not to mention outdated versions running on some sites may make it look slightly different).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  I tested it, and that's what it does!  And I found ctrl-Space does the same thing! Thanks again!

Comment: The photo the OP posted, wasn't a screenshot from TinyMCE, it was a screenshot from a react component called Quill. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill